# PHP Notice Suppression

Tags: php, checkbox, error-handling, get, undefined

I am retrieving some rows from a $_GET array and some of them are check box values. Since they will only display an "on" status in the $_GET array, I've devised the following solution to add an "off" to my strings that I will be sending to a client. Here is what it looks like:

```
if(!($_GET['active'][$row])){  //row is incremented in a loop
    $oactive = "off";
}else{
    $oactive = "FBINSERTa".":". "\"" . $_GET['active'][$row] ."\"";
}
```

Relatively simple and this works, putting off in $oactive if there is nothing at ['active'][$row]. However, if the value at $_GET['active'][$row] is undefined, PHP echoes a notice:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 6 in ...\page.php
>   on line x

I could suppress it with error_reporting() but I'd like to find a better way. Any ideas?

Comment: Check if the value `isset` before trying to use it.

Comment: A better question title would be, how do I prevent the notice, not suppress the message.

Comment: Do input validation before you use it.

Comment: @StevenV To be fair, the last sentence says "I could suppress it with error_reporting() but **I'd like to find a better way**"

Comment: You did say it, and I applaud you for wanting to do it right. But a lot of people around here will judge a question solely on it's title, and as you stated there should be a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that it's set before trying to use it, with [`isset`](https://www.php.net/isset)

```
if(isset($_GET['active'][$row]) && $_GET['active'][$row]==false){
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`isset`](http://php.net/isset):

```
if(isset($_GET['active'][$row])){  //row is incremented in a loop
    $oactive = "off";
}else{
    $oactive = "FBINSERTa".":". "\"" . $_GET['active'][$row] ."\"";
}
```

The other option is to include an `input` with type `hidden` and a default value ("off" I guess) in your markup immediately before each checkbox (and with the same name as), this way the value of the checkbox will take precidence if checked when the form is submitted, otherwise the default value from the hidden input will get submitted.

Example:

```
<input type="hidden" name="myCheckbox" value="off" />
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="myCheckbox" value="on" />
  Check me!
</label>
```